# Common method for populating different Objects similar structure

Tags: java, refactoring

I have two objects CreateDocumentHeader and RetrieveDocumentHeader which have very similar structure. I'm reading each of the object and populating a DTO.  I don't want to create different methods for each object. How can I write a single method for populating them. Here are the two classes.

```
public class CreateDocumentHeaderType {
    protected CreateAdminRecordType administrativeRecord;
    protected CreateControlRecordType controlRecord;
    public CreateAdminRecordType getAdministrativeRecord() {
        return administrativeRecord;
    }
    public void setAdministrativeRecord(CreateAdminRecordType value) {
        this.administrativeRecord = value;
    }
    public CreateControlRecordType getControlRecord() {
        return controlRecord;
    }
    public void setControlRecord(CreateControlRecordType value) {
        this.controlRecord = value;
    }
}

public class RetrieveDocumentHeaderType {
    protected RetrieveAdminRecordType administrativeRecord;
    protected RetrieveControlRecordType controlRecord;
    public RetrieveAdminRecordType getAdministrativeRecord() {
        return administrativeRecord;
    }
    public void setAdministrativeRecord(RetrieveAdminRecordType value) {
        this.administrativeRecord = value;
    }
    public RetrieveControlRecordType getControlRecord() {
        return controlRecord;
    }
    public void setControlRecord(RetrieveControlRecordType value) {
        this.controlRecord = value;
    }
}
```

AdminstrativeRecord and ControlRecord for both the versions also have similar structures.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, and I'm really sorry, I missed to mention one point. The CreateDocumentHeaderType and RetrieveDocumentHeaderType etc are JAXB generated file, So I guess I cannot change them to implement or extend any Interface or class. I'm really sorry for this miss.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm missing something. Did you consider abstract parent class?

Answer (score 0):

I'll create an interface to describe the contracts that both classes respect.

```
public interface DocumentHeaderType {
    public AdminRecordType getAdminRecord() ;

    public ControlRecordType getControlRecord() ;
}
```

Next step is to provide a basic implementation through an abstract class.

```
public abstract class AbstractDocumentHeaderType implements DocumentHeaderType {
    private AdminRecordType adminRecord ;
    private ControlRecordType controlRecord ;

    public AdminRecordType getAdminRecord() {
        return adminRecord ;
    }
    public ControlRecordType getControlRecord() {
        return controlRecord ;
    }
    // setters ...
}
```

Now you just need to have you CreateDocumentRecordHeaderType and RetrieveDocumentRecordHeaderType to extend the abstract class.

```
public class CreateDocumentHeaderType extends AbstractDocumentHeaderType {
    // we inherit the getters and setters, we are pretty much set
}
```

Now to the point, the method to populate the values

```
public void populateDocumentRequest(AbstractDocumentHeaderType holder) {
    holder.setAdminRecord(...);
    holder.setControlRecord(...) ;
}
```

Hope this helps.